# Boost, spirit, qi : how to omit attribute in a rule

Tags: boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm slightly puzzled how to define spirit::qi rule being passed to qi::parse() that should omit firts "," occurance. Say, I use the following code that compiles :

```
std::string out_str; int out_int;
std::string s2(",345");
bool rc = qi::parse(s2.begin(), s2.end(), qi::omit[qi::lit(",")] >>
                                          qi::int_, out_int);
```

But the code does not :

```
bool rc = qi::parse(s2.begin(), s2.end(), qi::omit[qi::lit(",")] >>
                                          qi::as_string[*qi::digit], out_str);
```

emitting error :
`boost\boost_1_64_0\boost\spirit\home\qi\detail\assign_to.hpp(153): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const std::string' to 'char'`

Could somebody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: IIRC, `lit` doesn't synthesize an attribute, so the `omit` seems rendundant.

Comment: You are right. But changing to qi::omit[qi::char_] >> qi::as_string[*qi::digit] doesn't work for me as well.

Comment: In similar vein, the synthesized attribute of `*qi::digit` will be a sequence of characters. That can already be assigned to a `std::string`, so there's no reason for the `as_string` here either. Just write the grammar as `qi::lit(",") >> *qi::digit` -- https://wandbox.org/permlink/HGd0VTxt1i6jrkAX

Comment: Works fine, thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

Assumoing you really just wanted to parse a list of integers, where some elements might be mising, just spell it as you want it:

```
-uint_ % ','
```

That's all. And it does nicely parse into a `vector<T>` where T is an appropriate integral type that works nicely for your application domain.

### Demo

See **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JOYT3SGSEnXOkThk)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {"", ",", ",345", "1,,2,3,4,"}) {
        std::vector<int> the_important_stuff;
        bool ok = qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), -qi::uint_ % ',', the_important_stuff);

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Input '" << input << "' parsed into " << the_important_stuff.size() << " integers\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Input '" << input << "' failed to parse\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
Input '' parsed into 0 integers
Input ',' parsed into 0 integers
Input ',345' parsed into 1 integers
Input '1,,2,3,4,' parsed into 4 integers
```

### Bonus

Too *also* ignore any insignificant whitespace (i.e. not within a number), change the invocation to

```
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), -qi::uint_ % ',', qi::space, the_important_stuff);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the point is that I don't need a vector<>. Say, I have a string keeping fixed length words separated by "," (e.g. : "#B7C82,33,9991,10!", where B7C82-id, "33"-should be a string of fixed length=2, "9991"-should be a string of fixed legth=4, etc). I know I may set qi::_pass=false in semantic action by verifying generated attribute length, but I prefer to have something like qi::lit(",") >> qi::repeat(2)[qi::char_] >> qi::lit(","). To be honest, I'm still puzzled why qi::as_string[] breaks compilation.

Comment: Container attributes are very flexible. You can have many sub expressions building a single container attribute, which does lead to potential for ambiguity/wrong heuristics. However, you _still_ want to express the _intent_ of the grammar, rather than the "how". Which means you should simply write `qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 2, 2>` instead of `qi::repeat(2)[qi::char_]`. `The documentation says that `qi::as_string` synthesizes a char-container, which is not what you need.

Comment: On a side note: If you need the string source for a bunch of stuff, wrap it in `qi::raw` (e.g. `raw[int_ % ',']`).

Comment: Thanks for tip about qi::raw! Live working example : [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H4JB2ABWHaDIdHOG). However, I still have only a guess why qi::raw[qi::uint_parser<unsigned, 10, 3, 3>{}] emits attribute with only 1st character as qi::raw should return a range.